# ExoPlayer show subtitles

Tags: android, exoplayer

I already searched but I couldn't find any solution to my problem.
I play a video source like this:

```
DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(getActivity(), Util.getUserAgent(getActivity(), "UA")));
MediaSource videoSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(Uri.parse(source));
simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
simpleExoPlayer.prepare(videoSource);
```

This "source" may have a subtitle track (embedded, if there's one it's already in the video and I don't want to import a srt file), how do I detect if there's a subtitle track, get a list of them and show the subtitles at the bottom of the video?

Also, how do I personalize them? I would like to have the white on a black background.

Comment: Hi look for this demo this is the demo from where i have created entire app with exoplayer and if you still get stuck let me know will help you.Happy coding  demo link :https://github.com/mitchtabian/Spotify-Clone

Comment: Hi, which part of project is about subtitles? I was looking at PlayerAdapter but I don't think I'm right

Comment: Also try to look into this :Disabling subtitles in Exoplayer leaves the last caption left on the screen #3547 https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/3547

Comment: Well you can see that when he creates a SingleSampleMediaSource he has a subtitle uri, but I don't: the subtitles are embedded in the video source. What should I do in my case?